# Render ExtJS view.View in grid.Panel using object array within a row element as view data

Tags: json, extjs, grid

I have an ExtJS grid.Panel, within which I have to render a set amount of information in an Ext.view.View. The data in question is packaged as a JSON object contained within the JSON object for the row, similar to this:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            firstName: "Bob",
            lastName: "Bobkins",
            age: 37,
            steps: [
                {
                    stepNumber: 1,
                    stepName: "Step 1",
                    status: "Complete"
                },
                {
                    stepNumber: 2,
                    stepName: "Step 2",
                    status: "Complete"
                },
                {
                    stepNumber: 3,
                    stepName: "Step 3",
                    status: "Incomplete"
                },
                {
                    stepNumber: 4,
                    stepName: "Step 4",
                    status: "Incomplete"
                },
                {
                    stepNumber: 5,
                    stepName: "Step 5",
                    status: "Incomplete"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            firstName: "Jane",
            lastName: "Jankins",
            age: 26,
            steps: [
                {
                    stepNumber: 1,
                    stepName: "Step 1",
                    status: "Complete"
                },
                {
                    stepNumber: 2,
                    stepName: "Step 2",
                    status: "Complete"
                },
                {
                    stepNumber: 3,
                    stepName: "Step 3",
                    status: "Complete"
                },
                {
                    stepNumber: 4,
                    stepName: "Step 4",
                    status: "Complete"
                },
                {
                    stepNumber: 5,
                    stepName: "Step 5",
                    status: "Incomplete"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My grid intends to, per top-level item, render separate columns for the firstName, lastName and age components, and render each step in a view for the steps component.

I can see the information for the steps in the browser console log as an object; can I render the information in the object to an Ext.view.View rendered within the grid? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your Ext.view.View to  a store with the fields in the steps object, and then use the following code to load the store data:

```
 var steps = selectedData.steps[0];
 myStore.loadData(steps);
```

the above code is an example for load the steps in the array position 0 of the selected person.